# $(\forall y(Q(y)∨\exists xQ(x)))\iff \exists yQ(y)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $Q(x)$ be a quantifer for the universe $\mathbb{Z}^+$. I want to check whether $$(\forall y(Q(y)∨\exists xQ(x)))\iff \exists yQ(y)$$

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

If the right holds, then for any $y$, $\exists x Q(x)$ holds, hence "$Q(y)$ or $\exists x Q(x)$" also holds.

If the left holds, pick an arbitrary $y$, then either $Q(y)$ holds which proves the right by letting $x=y$, or "$\exists x Q(x)$" which is literally the right side.